# PHP: как работать с куки? Они разные из разных папок?

Tags: php, cookie

Файл php в папке `scripts`. Выполняю

```
$parent_id = 3333;
setcookie( "parent_id", $parent_id);
```

Потом выполняется php в корне сайта, читаю куки:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['parent_id'])){
        $parent_id = $_COOKIE[ 'parent_id' ];
    }
    else {
        $parent_id = 9999;
        setcookie( "parent_id", $parent_id);
    }
```

В итоге, получаются две одноименные куки (смотрю через браузер - просмотр и удаление куки), у одного

имя: `parent_id`, значение: `9999`, путь: `/`

у другого

имя: `parent_id`, значение: `3333`, путь: `/scripts`

Как писать/читать куки из разных папок? Мне нужен `$parent_id` ообщий для всего сайта.

Comment: что за папки? Вы с веб работаете?

Comment: обычные папки в корне сайта. assets, css, images, scripts

Comment: `setcookie("parent_id", $parent_id, 0, 'site.ru/');`

Comment: так этот path это не путь к папке assets/ css/ images/ и т д!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала начнём с теории. Что такое `Cookie` ? Это пакет информации, который храниться в браузере пользователя и отправляется всякий раз когда пользователь делает запрос на сайт, будь то переход по ссылке или загрузка .css файла. В данном случае то, что вы называете папкой - это не папка. Это настройка `path` для определённых куки. Браузер, исходя из URL определяет если path начинается также, как и url, то он отправляет куки.

Приведём простой пример.

```
setcookie(/*Key:*/'test', /*Value:*/3, /*Expire*/0, /*Path:*/ '/hel');
```

Этот код создатся куки `test` со значением `3` до закрытия браузера по пути `/hel`. Браузер будет отсылать эту печеньку на сервер при дуступе к папке /hello_world, к файлу hello.txt и т.д.

Если вы хотите получать доступ к одной и той же печеньке с разных **путей**, то устанавливайте `path` на `/` таким простым образом:
`setcookie('test', 32, 0, '/');`

Советую подробно ознакомиться как с самой документацией языка, так и с конкретно кукисами на сайте php.net: [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php), а также обратить внимание на [сессии](http://www.softtime.ru/bookphp/gl8_1.php), ключевое отличие последних - хранение всех данных на сервере, а не в браузере (кроме id сессии)